# Solr schema design with respect to cassandra(no sql database)

Tags: php, solr, cassandra

I am using cassandra as database and solr as indexing engine. Do I need any solr schema design for these data as in cassandra?
As we are not using schema for cassandra and no field types, all data are saved as utf type. so I am a little bit confused if we need a proper schema design for solr with resepect to the  fields in cassandra or not?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the Solr integration provided with DataStax Enterprise?

Comment: I am using a cassandra triggers for indexing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Unlike, Cassandra, Solr requires a [schema definition](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml). When new columns are inserted into the Cassandra column family, your trigger will have to update the Solr schema in order for those fields to be searchable.

In answer to the questioner's follow on comment below about dynamic fields: Yes, you can use dynamic fields as a mechanism to map previously unknown columns with particular name patterns to types in the Solr index.  But (apologies for being pedantic), that *is* a schema definition.

Perhaps it achieves your goal of not having to update the Solr schema when new columns are inserted into Cassandra, but it does not allow them to have arbitrary names, as Cassandra allows.

Comment: as addition to this answer. The SOLR schema is the way u tell the SOLR engine how to index each field, as the various rules of filtering and tokenizing are part of the field definition in SOLR.

Comment: Thanks.But can't we use dynamic field definition for this purpose as defined with in the solr schema.